# Getting full URL with jQuery including parameters after question mark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pathname

I am trying to use jQuery to get the current full URL of a page. The URL of a page looks like this:

http://myurl.com/ebook?page=43

If I use `window.location.pathname` it only returns everything before the ? so I would just get

http://myurl.com/ebook

How can I get the entire URL?

Comment: Good References never hurt: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have:

```
window.location.href
```

and also:

```
document.URL
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to return the whole URL, you need to use [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.href).

Using [`window.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.pathname) only returns the path portion of the URL which excludes the query parameters and fragment (i.e., starting at the `/` following the *host* but only up to a `?` or `#`).

Example:

```
> window.location.pathname
"/ebook"
> window.location.href
"http://example.com/ebook?page=43"
```

Also, see the documentation for [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) for more available properties.